# get 4 int values from 2 bool variables

Tags: c#

i have a function with two bool parameters, i want elegantly build 4 options based on two bool input parameters. For example :

```
object GetSomeValue(bool a, bool b)
{   
    var intValue = //do something with a and b to get int value
    switch(intValue){
        case 3
           return ...
        case 2 
           return ...
        case 1
           return ...
        case 0
           return ...
    }   
}
```

as you understand, i mean  4 bit combinations from 2 bool vars : 00, 01, 10, 11. i ma looking to proper way how to get 4 int from 2 bool vars

Comment: Perhaps a [Flags enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types#enumeration-types-as-bit-flags) is a better option than two `bool` parameters.

Comment: ^Yep. Otherwise, if a is supposed to be bit 1 and b is supposed to be bit 0 then have result = (if(a)? 2: 0) + (if(b)? 1:0);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the `bool` variables to `int` and perform one shift and one OR operation:

```
var intValue = (Convert.ToInt32(a) << 1) | Convert.ToInt32(b);
```

Comment: thanks , i would like to add another solution : `Convert.ToInt32($"{Convert.ToInt32(true)}{Convert.ToInt32(true)}", 2)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bitwise `|` operator:

```
int GetSomeValue(bool a, bool b)
{   
    var intValue = 0;
    intValue = a ? intValue | 2;
    intValue = b ? intValue | 1;
    return intValue;
}
```

Basically if you have an array of bools:

```
int GetSomeValue(bool[] a)
{   
    var intValue = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< a.Length; i++)
        if(a[i]) intValue |= 1 << i;
    return intValue;
}
```

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams whats wrong should be edited. right? but I'm a bad ninja ;)

Answer (score 2):

Couple more plays

```
bool a=true; bool b=true;
var intValue1 = Convert.ToInt32(a) *2 + Convert.ToInt32(b);
var intValue2 = (a?2:0) + Convert.ToInt32(b);
var intValue3 = (a?2:0) + (b?1:0);

//
int bools2int(params bool[] bb)
{
    var i = new int[1];
    BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(bb);
    bitArray.CopyTo(i,0);
    var intValue4 = i[0];
    return intValue4;
}
```

and using bools2int in patterns way:

```
void bools2actions(bool[] bb, Action[] actions)
{
    var i = bools2int(bb);
    actions[i]();
}

void demo()
{
    bools2actions(new bool[]{true, true},
          new Action[]
          {
              ()=>Console.WriteLine(0),
              ()=>Console.WriteLine(1),
              ()=>Console.WriteLine(2),
              ()=>Console.WriteLine(3),
          }
         );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function such as this to convert your booleans to an int.  This will accept any number of boolean flags:

```
public int ConvertFlagsToInt(params bool[] flags)
{
    int result=0;
    for(var i=0; i<flags.Length; i++)
    {
        result = result * 2 + (flags[i] ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example Code:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertFlagsToInt(false, false));
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertFlagsToInt(false, true));
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertFlagsToInt(true, false));
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertFlagsToInt(true, true));
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertFlagsToInt(true, true, true));
}
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
7
```

If you wanted the inverse of this function too...

```
public IEnumerable<bool> ConvertIntToFlags(int input, int numberOfFlags = 0)
{
    var exponent = Math.Max(numberOfFlags, Math.Floor(Math.Log(input, 2)));
    var remainder = input;
    for (var i=exponent; i>=0; i--)
    {
        int bin = (int)(Math.Pow(2, i));
        var result = remainder >= bin;
        if (result) remainder -= bin;
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

---

Or if you want a fast solution for only 2 bools:

```
static readonly int[][] map = new []{ new []{0,1}, new []{2,3}};
int ConvertFlagsToInt (bool a, bool b) => map[a?1:0][b?1:0];
```